# how to create folder and save file in it using c#

Tags: c#

I create new folder but how to save file in that please help me.

```
string createfolder = "E:/tmp/jobres/" + uId;    
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createfolder);
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/tmp/jobres/" + AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
```

but how to store my file in created folder?

Comment: How do you store your file now?

Comment: AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/tmp/jobres/" + AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));

Comment: Try this:
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/tmp/jobres/" + uid + AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));

Comment: no still its not working. "uid" is a new created folder.

Comment: @Arvaan OP's creating his dir in a different place. Also your comment shows why `Path.Combine` is safer than `+` (your solution is missing a slash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `MapPath` on save, your directory may be created in the wrong spot. You should be using `MapPath` when creating your directory as well:

```
var createfolder = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/tmp/jobres/"), uId.ToString());    
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createfolder);
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(createdFolder, AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 string createfolder = "/tmp/jobres/" + uId;                           
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createfolder);
 AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(createfolder,AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.