# want to save finger print image in database and also want to retrieve the same image

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

This is my code i saved finger print image from picturebox to a folder and then want to save in binary format .after that when user input their finger print from bio metric scanner verify option will check the finger print image with saved image in database.but i cannot understand how to save my image and how to retrieve ?
please help me if there is any mistake .

```
         string fname = ID.Text + ".jpg";

     string folder="C:/Users/SATYASHANTI/Desktop/ARMSPROJECT/rupak/personal"; 
       string pathstring = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, fname);
       Image a = picFinger.Image;
       a.Save(pathstring);


        string imglog = "";
        byte[] img = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(imglog, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        img= br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into finger_check(emp_uniqueID,leftThum) values('"+ ID_combobox.Text+"',@leftThum)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@leftThum",img));
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ID_combobox.Text = string.Empty;
        picFinger.Image = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the image from database, you may make a select query to get image data from the database. The type of sql image type in .net is Byte[]. You may refer to MS doc ([SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)). Below is the sample code:

USER_INPUT: the fingerprint image data from scanner

IS_FINGERPRINT_MATCH: A function return boolean value which check 2 image is same fingerprint or not. You should refer to the scanner's document you are using to see whether there is such function provided. If not, you have to find related algorithm or API to complete your task.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select emp_uniqueID  ,leftThum from finger_check";
cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var tempEmpId= reader["emp_uniqueID"];
        var storedFingerPrintBinary = (byte[])reader["leftThum"];

        if(IS_FINGERPRINT_MATCH(storedFingerPrintBinary, USER_INPUT))
        {
           //do something
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ,but i want to retrieve only the image data not the path because i am using bio metric scanner for scan finger print so if i retrieve the path it will not able to verify any finger .

Comment: you may use the file directory path to retrieve the image binary data in C# and then use it for the verification.

Comment: but how i save my image binary data path ?

Comment: It depends on your setup. If you would like to do so, the computer which hosts the database should be able to connect to the host of the site (e.g.. in the same network). Save the image to the db's directory first, then save the path as string into db table. When the image is needed, query the path from the db table and get the image data in that path. 

The way to save file you may refer the question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842761/how-to-create-folder-and-save-file-in-it-using-c-sharp

Comment: thank you for ur commt, see i am creating windows application that verify finger prints , so i need to store my finger image in database .i already saved it in database in binary for math .now i need only how to retrieve binary data from table and verify it with given image .

Comment: I edited my answer, see if it can help you or not. Basically, you can make a simple select query to get your data if you have saved the image in database.

Comment: can u please explain me how to save the image and in which format ?

Comment: and also i want to retrieve emp_uniqueID from database based on finger print

Comment: I think the code you provided should be able to save the image. The way to save image to database is to convert the image file to binary data. What stored in database is the binary data. If you want to know what file format of the stored binary is, you should save image's extension/ file name into database.

Comment: For retrieving emp_uniqueID from database based on finger print, it may be out of the scope of this question. You may try to search related algorithm or API for this purpose.

Comment: thank you , and yes i want to retrieve the image and id also because i want to verify no duplicate value occur...please help me

Comment: Sorry that I may not be able to help you. I can only provide the general workflow for your reference. The fingerprint recognition is out of my knowledge. But you may look up the scanner's document or search related algorithm or API to complete the missing piece of the code.